# Android - Google Assistant not providing the number for CREATE_CALL BII

Tags: android, google-assistant, app-actions

I am trying to integrate CREATE_CALL  BII I can trigger my app using the voice command “Call <CONTACT_NAME> on <APP_NAME>” but I am facing a problem that the BII is only sending me the CONTACT_NAME but not the PHONE_NUMBER even though that contact is in android native Addressbook.

Following is my action:

```
<action intentName="actions.intent.CREATE_CALL">
    <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://fit-actions.firebaseapp.com/call{?callFormat,name,telephone}">
        <parameter-mapping urlParameter="callFormat" intentParameter="call.callFormat"/>
        <parameter-mapping urlParameter="name" intentParameter="call.participant.name" />
        <parameter-mapping urlParameter="telephone" intentParameter="call.participant.telephone" />
    </fulfillment>
</action>
```

Action is working perfectly with

> App Actions Test Tool

I am following https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/reference/built-in-intents/communications/create-call, even though I copied the same code from that link to my sample to make it work but I am getting the same result, the only name is there in my deep link but no phone number is there.

What I want to achieve the way Google Duo is doing shown in the following gif
[image: Making call using Duo]

Answer (score 1):

App Actions doesn't know how to look up additional information about the contact in the query.  The phone number is only provided if it was spoken in the request.

If you need a phone number for the contact, you will have to write code to query your address book using the name provided in the user's query.  You might find that the user's query is not specific enough to locate one specific contact, and in that case, you will have to provide a UI to disambiguate the request (e.g. if there are two people named "Lee", the user will need to be able to choose which one they meant).

Comment: Do you know (or guess) how Google Duo or Whatsapp are resolving the number for the spoken contact? It looks like for those apps the Google Assistant searches for the contact from the Contacts app (or even disambiguates the number in case of multiple numbers) and then triggers the app to initiate the call. I am trying to achieve something similar but can't get a clue how to do it.

Comment: Android has a way to query contacts on the device if you have permission to do so.

Comment: do I need to use Android Slice?

Comment: No, Android has an API for querying contacts.  Use that API to find a phone number for a name. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider

Comment: I understand that I need to query for contact, but what makes me confuse for disambiguating the request if I create a UI inside my application then the user has to interact physically which I don't want, what I want the way google duo is doing that google assistant ask from the user that which user you want to call, So for that thing to occur do I need to do something like creating Android Slice or there is some other way to achieve that?

Comment: A slice won't help you.  You have to write app code to disambiguate within your app after you receive the data from the BII. Maybe you could write a slice to do the disambiguation inline in Assistant, but you are still having to write that code.

Comment: If you look at the attached image it looks like the contact resolution is happening while staying inside the Google Assistant UI (which means the deep link is triggered afterward once the contact is found through the ContactsProvider). I have completely turned off the Contacts permission for Duo and it should not have access to the Contacts app at this moment.

Comment: There could be a slice rendering that information, but it must have custom written code to look up the number.  You will have to write that code.  The slice itself won't help you with that.  It just lets you show content outside your app.